PowerShell Call SSIS package, Pass Two (or More) Parameters
I am writing a group of PowerShell scripts to call SSIS packages, passing in the SQL password obtained from an Azure key vault.  When the SSIS package has a single connection it works just fine - this for instance:
    DTEXEC /FILE "./$ProcessName.dtsx" /CONFIGFILE "$ScriptDirectory\config\$env\$ProcessName.dtsConfig" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /CONSOLELOG SM /REPORTING EWCDI /SET "\Package.Connections[DATABASE.INC.DB].Properties[Password];$secretpwd" > $SSISLog

what is the syntax if there are 2 or more databases to pass the password in for?  I don't think I can include 2 SET statements

A SQL Server can have one or more databases.  You need a separate connection for each database.  You cannot have one connection for two databases.

yes, I need to pass in a password for each database connection - do I / can I enter 2 /SET statements or is there a way to create a collection of set parameters?

The credentials are in the connection string.  You need a separate connection string for each connection.  The dtsx is an xml file for processing instruction to SSIS, it is not the connection to the database.

The dtsx package has a separate connection for each database it needs.  That is not what I am asking.  What I want to know is how to build a DTEXEC statement that includes a connection object for 2 different connections (or more).  What syntax works?  My efforts to date throws an error.

According to the dtexec doc page you can have multiple /Set parameters. They even show an example with 2 /Set params.

Why do you need one statement ("a DTEXEC statement")?  Use two set statements.


When the SSIS package has a single connection it works just fine.
What is the syntax if there are 2 or more databases to pass the password in for?

Two Potential Solutions
#1
Setup an array with database names, then loop through each name to execute the DTEXEC command while injecting the database name and password into the command dynamically. This way handles multiple database connections without using multiple SET statements.
$dbs = @("DATABASE.INC.DB","DATABASE.INC.XY","DATABASE.INC.ABC");
foreach($db in $dbs){ 
    DTEXEC /FILE "./$ProcessName.dtsx" /CONFIGFILE "$ScriptDirectory\config\$env\$ProcessName.dtsConfig" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /CONSOLELOG SM /REPORTING EWCDI /SET "\Package.Connections[$db].Properties[Password];$secretpwd" > $SSISLog
    ##Write-Host "DTEXEC /FILE `"./$ProcessName.dtsx`" /CONFIGFILE `"$ScriptDirectory\config\$env\$ProcessName.dtsConfig`" /MAXCONCURRENT `" -1 `" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /CONSOLELOG SM /REPORTING EWCDI /SET `"\Package.Connections[$db].Properties[Password];$secretpwd`" > $SSISLog"
    };

#2
Define an array of database names, then use ForEach-Object to create another array of /SET statements for each database. Join the /SET statements into a single string and concatenate to the DTEXEC command at execution using multiple /SET statements in one execution.
$dbs = @("DATABASE.INC.DB","DATABASE.INC.XY","DATABASE.INC.ABC");
$sets = $dbs | ForEach-Object {"/SET `"\Package.Connection[$_].Properties[Password];$($secretpwd)`""};
$joinSets = $sets -join " ";

DTEXEC /FILE "./$ProcessName.dtsx" /CONFIGFILE "$ScriptDirectory\config\$env\$ProcessName.dtsConfig" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /CONSOLELOG SM /REPORTING EWCDI $joinSets > $SSISLog
##Write-Host "DTEXEC /FILE `"./$ProcessName.dtsx`" /CONFIGFILE `"$ScriptDirectory\config\$env\$ProcessName.dtsConfig`" /MAXCONCURRENT `" -1 `" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /CONSOLELOG SM /REPORTING EWCDI /SET $joinSets > $SSISLog"




/Set [$Sensitive::]propertyPath;value: (Optional). Overrides the
configuration of a parameter, variable, property, container, log
provider, Foreach enumerator, or connection within a package. When
this option is used, /Set changes the propertyPath argument to the
value specified. Multiple /Set options can be specified.
Source




Just as your PowerShell samples show and per the powershell tag on the question, it is assumed these commands run in powershell already for you right at the command terminal or script per your example with the variables in them, so this assumes the looped commands would work the same way. Otherwise you may need to explore Invoke-Expression to execute the commands as they are constructed. There are a lot of double quotes but I assume these run for you now and will with extended further variables right from PowerShell too. These would be the syntax and solutions you are after.

I took #2 - with a syntax correction - removed the /SET before $joinsets in the DTEXEC command - the $joinsets had /SET commands

Sorry for the oversight there, I've corrected this in #2 logic. Glad it helped you get a solution regardless.

I had to modify the /SET as follows: add .Value and wrap each password in a backslash doublequote as follows /SET ".....Properties[Password].Value";"22 character password" - the Password has to be included as a separate property on the ConnectionString in configuration
